# Can I somehow chain methods in PHP

Tags: php

Basically, I am looking for a way I could optimize the following.
Not really a PHP programmer, and in the Ruby world this would be easy, but at the moment I have this:

```
if(count($methods) == 1) {
    $resp = $this->$methods[0];
}
else if(count($methods) > 1) {
    $resp = $this->$methods[0]->$methods[1];
}
```

Is there somehow a way I could loop over the methods array here, and chain them together?

Thanks!

Comment: is `$methods` a function or array ?

Comment: Is `$methods` an array of functions?

Comment: "Methods" meaning a function you want to call, or a *property* you want to access? What you show is a property access, not a method invocation.

Comment: If the method you're calling returns an instance of a class or property you're accessing contains an instance of a class, you can chain them.

Comment: Do the methods actually need to be "chained", i.e. running against the *return value* of the previous one? Or do you just want to run an array of method names on a single object instance?

Comment: Quite right, they were properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is essentially an array reduction:

```
$resp = array_reduce($methods, function ($o, $p) { return $o->$p; }, $this);
```

It's unclear whether you want `$o->$p` (property access) or `$o->$p()` (method call), but you can figure that out.

Comment: As I said above, yes they are properties, let me have a play with what you are showing here.